# Group by fuzzy criterion

Tags: sql, group-by

Is there any way do this task in `SQL`:

Having a table of luggage names and its weights that looks like this

```
 luggage_id | luggage_name | luggage_weight   
------------+--------------+----------------  
          1 | Tom          |              2  
          2 | Kat          |              3  
          3 | Lil          |              4
```

ouput groups of things that differ in weight for less then or exactly D units. So if D equals to 1 we have to get

```
1. Tom, Kat
2. Kat, Lil
```

and if D equals to 2 we have to get

```
1. Tom, Kat, Lil
```

and if D is 0.5 we get

```
1. Tom
2. Kat
3. Lil
```

I tried to use cross join:

```
SELECT t1.luggage_name, t2.luggage_name
FROM Luggages t1, Luggages t2
WHERE ABS(t1.luggage_weight - t2.luggage_weight) <= 1
```

that resulted in

```
 luggage_name | luggage_name 
--------------+--------------
 Tom          | Tom
 Tom          | Kat
 Kat          | Tom
 Kat          | Kat
 Kat          | Lil
 Lil          | Kat
 Lil          | Lil
```

Is it possible to solve this problem with `SQL`?

`EDIT`
Ok, yes, we can write

```
SELECT t1.luggage_name, t2.luggage_name
FROM Luggages t1, Luggages t2
WHERE ABS(t1.luggage_weight - t2.luggage_weight) <= 1
      AND t1.luggage_id < t2.luggage_id
```

then we will get

```
 luggage_name | luggage_name 
--------------+--------------
 Tom          | Kat
 Kat          | Lil
```

That means that Tom is in group with Kat and Kat is in group with Lil.

But, let's say we have table with all the same weights

```
 luggage_id | luggage_name | luggage_weight 
------------+--------------+----------------
          1 | Tom          |              1
          2 | Kat          |              1
          3 | Lil          |              1
```

Then we will get

```
 luggage_name | luggage_name 
--------------+--------------
 Tom          | Kat
 Tom          | Lil
 Kat          | Lil
```

That means that Tom is with Kat and Lil that is correct, but next group, Kat with Lil is already in first group. I thought about this issue and can not figure out how to solve it. How to output only different groups?

Answer (score 3):

You need a condition to restrict the full Cartesian to a triangular join

```
SELECT t1.luggage_name, t2.luggage_name
FROM Luggages t1, Luggages t2
WHERE ABS(t1.luggage_weight - t2.luggage_weight) <= 1

AND
t1.luggageid < t2.luggageid
```

This removes unwanted pairs

Edit

You output would then be

```
 luggage_name | luggage_name 
--------------+--------------
 Tom          | Kat
 Kat          | Lil
```

When `d=0.5` then you have *no* pairs though because there is no difference less than 0.5. A list of singletons is actually *wrong* when compared to the output from `d <= 1`

Edit 2: Proof for those you don't get it...

```
DECLARE @luggage TABLE (luggageid int IDENTITY(1,1), luggage_name varchar(30), luggage_weight float)
INSERT @luggage (luggage_name, luggage_weight) VALUES ('Tom', 2), ('Kat', 3), ('Lil', 4)

SELECT t1.luggage_name, t2.luggage_name
FROM @luggage t1, @luggage t2
WHERE ABS(t1.luggage_weight - t2.luggage_weight) <= 1
AND
t1.luggageid < t2.luggageid


SELECT t1.luggage_name, t2.luggage_name
FROM @luggage t1, @luggage t2
WHERE ABS(t1.luggage_weight - t2.luggage_weight) <= 2
AND
t1.luggageid < t2.luggageid


SELECT t1.luggage_name, t2.luggage_name
FROM @luggage t1, @luggage t2
WHERE ABS(t1.luggage_weight - t2.luggage_weight) <= 0.5
AND
t1.luggageid < t2.luggageid
```

Comment: Won't that always output one pair per group?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.luggage_name, MIN(t2.luggage_name) GroupsWith
FROM Luggages t1
JOIN Luggages t2 ON ABS(t1.luggage_weight - t2.luggage_weight) <= 1
AND ((t1.luggage_weight < t2.luggage_weight)
  OR (t1.luggage_weight = t2.luggage_weight AND t1.luggage_name < t2.luggage_name))
GROUP BY t1.luggage_name
ORDER BY t1.luggage_name
```

This will show a chain of grouped users without any duplicates, so if you have

```
Tom-2, Kat-3, Lil-4, Bob-5
```

They are all D=1 from each other. If your query has D=1, it will show

```
Kat Lil
Lil Bob
Tom Kat
```

Which shows the entire group Tom->Kat->Lil->Bob.

Comment: Interesting. This works where all have the same weight but the output (not your code) still feels wrong